# Wrong result with IF statement

Tags: php, css, sql, oracle

I am having an issue which I don't quite understand why. I am messing around with the timeglider timeline and I am looking to display critical data with red color and normal data with black. Each time the `while` runs, it puts a registry(`id,title,startdate,...`) into the array. The timeline also has an option (`css_class`) that allows to change a resgitry css. For that I do the following: `if ($res2['CRITICO'] == '1'){$vs['css_class']='hot-event';}`.`Hot-event` is just a css class I created which has `color:red`. The problem is that the result, apart from turning where `CRITICO =='1'` into red (which is expected), it ends turning into red some registries where `CRITICO =='0'`, which makes no sense since I have the `If`. Also why just a selected few and not all is even weirder. In the database `CRITICO` is varchar type so I don't get what's wrong with my `If` statement

```
$query2 = "SELECT DISTINCT PROCESSO,  TO_CHAR(DATAMSG,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi') AS DATAMSG, CATEGORIA_DESC, VALOR, CRITICO FROM PATIENT_TIMELINE_VS20152S c
     WHERE PROCESSO = ".$nprocesso." AND (trim(CATEGORIA_DESC)) IN ('ART_DIA','SPO2','ART_SYS','TEMP_T1','ECG_HR') AND  TO_CHAR(DATAMSG,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') IN
          (SELECT DISTINCT MIN(TO_CHAR(DATAMSG,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
          FROM PATIENT_TIMELINE_VS20152S A
          where c.CATEGORIA_DESC = a.CATEGORIA_DESC
          GROUP BY PROCESSO, TO_CHAR(DATAMSG,'YYYYMMDDHH24'))
          ORDER BY  PROCESSO, DATAMSG ASC";
    $result2 = oci_parse($connect, $query2);
    oci_execute($result2);

$a=0;

while($res2 = oci_fetch_array($result2) AND $res5 = oci_fetch_array($result5))  {
 $a++;   
 $vs['id']= $a;
 $vs['title']='VS - '.$res2['CATEGORIA_DESC'];
 $vs['startdate']=$res2['DATAMSG'];
 $vs['enddate']=$res2['DATAMSG'];
 $vs['description']= '1ºH - '.$res2['VALOR'].'| MAX - '.$res5['MAXVAL'].'| MIN - '.$res5['MINVAL'].'| AVG - '.$res5['AVGVAL'].'| crit- '.$res2['CRITICO'];
 $vs['date_display']='ho';
 $vs['icon']='plus_blue.png';
 $vs['importance']='30';

 if ($res2['CRITICO'] == '1'){
 $vs['css_class']='hot-event';
 }
 array_push($vs1,$vs);
```

Comment: You're missing else part. You're setting class to hot event and then it stays hot. at least as far as i can see. However, you need to format the code a bit better. Also, what's with `result5`?

Comment: Why do I need the `else` part? It is supposed to just run the `if` part if the condition verifies. `result5` is  data from another query, not relevant to the question just part of the code.

Comment: are you sure? use var_dump or debugger to see what they are actually equal to. Try using  '===' rather than '=='.

Comment: Since you are not initializing your array `$vs` on each loop, then any values that are set in 1 loop, it will retain that value in the next loop if not overwritten. You can do 3 things - (1) do an `else{$vs['css_class']=='';}` as @hummingBird suggested. (2) reset the array on each loop `$vs = array();`. or (3) set the default value at the start of the loop `$vs['css_class']=='';`

Comment: I reseted the array on each loop and it worked @Sean, although I don't understand why. Can you explain it, please? Also is it better to reinitialized the array everytime to prevent future errors?

Comment: I find it a good practice to reinitialize the array on each loop, to ensure there is not any dangling values, as was your case with `$vs['css_class']`. As to why - when a variable, or array value, is set it will stay set, even on with a loop unless it is unset (which reinitializing the array does) or is overwritten to a new value.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for help everyone!